# How to play video in videoview with below link?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

Link is :  **http://live.ramalin.com/inter/bbc-sport.html**

When I tried to run in videoview it gives me error with can't play video

```
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
```

I have implemented videoview as below

```
private void PlayVideo() {

        Log.e("video url", videourl);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(videourl);
        android.widget.MediaController mediaController = new android.widget.MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(android.media.MediaPlayer mp) {
                videoView.start();
            }
        });
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(android.media.MediaPlayer mp) {

            }
        });
}
```

Any help will appreciated Thank you.

Comment: the link is not a **video**, but an **HTML page**.VideoView can't play HTML pages.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out. I got it. I have to use webview for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would stream the video like this [example](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/streaming-video-in-android-apps--cms-19888).